# functions in R, without specifying data

Tags: r, lapply

I have the following data:

```
x <- 11
w <- "12AAB"
y <- "var1"
```

I also have a function `funky(x,w,y){}`

With the above 3 constants as inputs I can apply the following:

```
funky(x = x, w = w, y = y)
```

Which imports a bunch of data and performs some calculations and saves the file in a specific folder. I now however want to expand the function over to different "vars" where y is a character vector. For instance;

```
x <- 11
w <- "12AAB"
y <- c("var1", "va2", "var3")
```

How can I use `lapply` to run the function using `x = 11`, `w = 12AAB` and firstly run using `y = var1`, then secondly `y = var2` etc.

I do not have anything specific to apply the function to so I cannot use `lapply(data, funky)`

Comment: hi User, please provide a minimum reproducible example so we can run this on our own machines and explore and provide solutions. thanks :) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You want `Map` I think - `Map(funky, x, w, y)`

Comment: with `map` I get this error: `Error: `.x` is not a vector (closure)`

Comment: @user113156 - `Map` not `map`.

Comment: ha, doh! Yeh that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `y` with `lapply`, hard-coding `x` and `w`.

```
lapply(y, funky, x = x, w = w)
```

This will run `funky` the length `n` of `y` times, with

```
funky(x = x, w = w, y = y[1])
funky(x = x, w = w, y = y[...])
funky(x = x, w = w, y = y[n])
```

Comment: Excellent answer!+1 Just to add to that, note the warning and best practice from `?lapply` to avoid being caught out:

> "Arguments in ... cannot have the same name as any of the other arguments, and care may be needed to avoid partial matching to FUN. In general-purpose code it is good practice to name the first two arguments X and FUN if ... is passed through: this both avoids partial matching to FUN and ensures that a sensible error message is given if arguments named X or FUN are passed through ..."

So suggestion would be to name X and FUN like: `lapply(X=y, FUN=funky, x = x, w = w)`